# After the First Opium war, Why didn't Britain demand large amounts of territory from China?

Tags: china, british-empire

The first Opium war was a total British victory. With such a total British victory, and with the [expansionist ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historiography_of_the_British_Empire) that existed in Britain, forcing China into an unconditional surrender seemed to be the the most likely action. I am aware that the British didn't have enough manpower to hold such a vast territory with such a large population, so Britain would not be able to topple the Qing Dynasty completely and set up another British colony, but it would have been possible to force China to cede, say, Tibet and Xinjiang to expand British India, and the major ports with the Pacific(Shanghai, Guangzhou, and such). This seems to be what the British would most likely do, to take from China all that it could realistically hold. The Chinese would comply with virtually any treaty, them being crippled by the British. Instead, the only territory ceded was Hong Kong and the island of Kowloon, which, at this time, was little more than a random rock. Why didn't Britain demand large amounts of territory from China?

Comment: You might want to include some support for the existence of "expansionist ideals" in Britain at the time, with some indication of how widespread these ideals were in the ruling classes.

Comment: @SteveBird - Is the link I added sufficient for that? Or can we just rephrase the statement a little? "The Late Modern UK was kind of into imperialism" doesn't really strike me as the kind of assertion that is non-trivial enough to require references.

Comment: @T.E.D. Since the link is to a rather lengthy page about the entire historiography of the British Empire, there's nothing that directly indicates that 'expansionist ideals' were particularly in favour with the ruling classes at the time of the First Opium War.

Comment: The war was about allowing trade, not about seizing territory. The 'random rock' just happened to have an excellent harbour and was defensible with 19th century naval technology. Ideal for a trading gateway into China (as history later proved).

Comment: There is a widespread theory that the British Empire, if you want to call it that, was just the "nation of shopkeepers" keeping trade routes open. The rest was an unplanned burden of responsibility. If you subscribe to this idea then your question is meaningless - that's not what they wanted.

Comment: Allthough fiction, this novel contains enough historical background to answer your questions: [Tai-Pan (novel) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai-Pan_(novel))

Comment: Adding to what RedSonja says, the First Opium War (1839-42) was before British India came under British government rule (India was originally a private trade area, dependent on cooperative locals, often ruled by pitting local monarchs against each other), something that only happened as a consequence of the Indian Mutiny (1857) and the need to prevent further risings. So it's certainly questionable if Britain wanted large Asian territories.

Comment: [The Opium War: Drugs, Dreams, and the Making of Modern China](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07MW9T64Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) by [julia-lovell](https://www.bbk.ac.uk/our-staff/profile/8006435/julia-lovell) will answer your question better than any other source you can find. But it is a thick book.

Comment: By "better than any other source you can find" I mean the English material, not all the sources because I believe there are Chinese materials better explain that. I will try to provide an answer myself later.

Answer (score 7):

> I am aware that the British didn't have enough manpower to hold such a vast territory with such a large population, so Britain would not be able to topple the Qing Dynasty completely and set up another British colony

You answered it yourself:

- not enough manpower
- territory was too large
- too many people to control

The UK wasn't always looking for new territories. There were both a colonial and an anti-colonial factions in parliament. Sometimes the colonials were the majority, and sometimes the anti-colonials.

Prime minister at the time of the [First Opium War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Opium_War) was [sir Robert Peel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Peel). He's remembered as the creator of modern police ('bobbies'). Sir Robert focused on domestic affairs, and was a proponent of free trade. Colonialism wasn't very high on his agenda, if at all. Colonizing China, not even remotely.

It's a myth that the UK (or any other colonizing nation) colonized whatever and whenever they could. Those countries have different political parties with different views on colonialism. Some are in favour, others firmly against. It simply depends on which party is in office.

[Charles George Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_George_Gordon) (of Khartoum fame), for example, had the bad luck he was sent under an anti-colonial government.

Another example is the [First Boer War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Boer_War) in which Transvaal gained its independence. A pro-colonial government would never have granted it. The prime minister was [Gladstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Ewart_Gladstone), who was *[somewhat of]* a liberal. Not a supporter of colonialism.